# How do I convert byte to string?

Tags: c#, c++

Is there any fast way to convert given byte (like, by number - `65`) to it's text hex representation?

Basically, I want to convert array of bytes into (I am hardcoding resources) their code-representation like

```
BYTE data[] = {0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, ... }
```

*How do I automate this `Given byte -> "0x0A" string` conversion?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you can use `stringstream`, and ssprintf.

Some compilers may have an `itoa` method that will convert an integer into its textual representation.

These are portable functions.  You can always add an integer to '0' to get a textual digit and likewise with 'A' and 'a'.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.leunen.com/cbuilder/convert.html;

```
template<class T>
std::string ToHex(const T &value)
{
  std::ostringstream oss;
  if(!(oss<<std::hex<<value))
     throw exception("Invalid argument");
  return oss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

typedef int BYTE;


int main()
{

    BYTE data[] = {0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01 };

    for(int loop=0;loop < 4; ++loop)
    {
        std::cout << "Ox" 
                  << std::setw(2) 
                  << std::setfill('0') 
                  << std::hex 
                  << data[loop] 
                  << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=361158 ?

Answer (score 1):

*Thank you, just to mention, I used the following construction:*

```
std::stringstream stream;
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
   stream << "0x" << std::hex << (short)data[i] << ", ";
}
std::string result = stream.str();
```